Feller’s insect problem - combining binomial and poisson

I wonder whether my reasoning here is not hand-wavy: we can imagine each egg being laid on the unit time interval, and further each egg has probability p surviving, so the probability of a surviving egg (and thus the corresponding point) depends on both its appearance and its development, together this is some probability $p’$. From here we estimate that our distribution for the number of surviving eggs should follow Poisson with some unknown parameter. Now $\lambda$ is roughly the average number of laid eggs per unit time interval if we were to observe the insect over large period of time (several unit intervals), and by a law of large numbers $\lambda p$ is the average number of eggs survived per unit interval, thus this should be the corresponding parameter.
I know there is a standard solution as in an earlier question. However, I wonder if this intuitive explanation is rigorous enough for the estimate? Thanks!

It does look hand-wavy - all the statements are true, but may not amount to a proof.    The key points are (a) the Poisson distribution for developing eggs and (b) a parameter of $\lambda p$.  For (b), you can better appeal to the law of total expectation for a mean of  $\lambda p$ rather than the law of large numbers - the original question does not mention time.
